# How to get data based on value from firebase database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i'm trying to get the data based on "Payments" in child "State" in my structured data
[My Structured firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7A99.jpg)

I used this

```
salesRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                .child("Orders")
                .orderByKey().startAt("Payments").endAt("Payments"+"\uf8ff");
```

but i got nothing back.What was wrong ? What should i use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to do the following:

```
salesRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Orders").orderByChild("state").equalTo("Waiting Payments Config");
```

`orderByChild` will take the name of an attribute as an argument and, `equalTo` will take the value of that attribute as an argument.

Check the docs:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data

Answer (score 4):

You're ordering by key (the 089630116543 etc) and then saying you want keys starting at "Payments" and ending at "Payments\uf8ff". There aren't any such keys, which is why you're not getting back any results.

I haven't used Firebase Realtime Database myself (just Firestore, from C#, which is related but not quite the same). I *suspect* if you change `orderByKey()` to `orderByChild("state")` that would fix it:

```java
salesRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
    .child("Orders")
    .orderByChild("state").startAt("Payments").endAt("Payments\uf8ff");
```

Note that this won't find the value where State is "Waiting Payments Config" because that doesn't *start* with Payments. If you actually want a "contains" kind of query, that could be trickier (or infeasible, I'm not sure).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen: No sure what you mean by `-L....` but I'll remove that "other option" part.